# Como pegar o valor do ID da tag i?

Tags: jquery

Tenho as seguintes DIVS:

```
  <div id="img_btn2"><a href="#modal1" class="modal-trigger btn-flat"><i class="material-icons icone_branco">alarm</i></a></div>
  <div id="img_btn"><i id="img_lamp1" class="material-icons icone_branco">lightbulb_outline</i></div>
  <div id="nome_btn1" align="center">QUARTO</div>
  <div id="botoes" class="row" align="center">
      <div class="switch" align="center"><label>Desligado<input id="btn_cliente_on1" class="btn_onoff" value="http://192.168.10.102" type="checkbox"><span class="lever"></span>Ligado</label></div>
  </div>
```

E quero pegar o ID da TAG **i**, via JQuery, mas não estou conseguindo via closest.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_onoff', function(){ 
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var target = $(this).closest('i').attr('id');
var cmd = $(this).val(); 
console.log(target);
});
```

Como resolver??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) nesse caso é limitado pois não tens um elemento pai de todo esse bloco de HTML. Mas podes usar o [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) com o [.prevAll()](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) assim:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn_onoff', function() {
  var id = this.id;
  var target = $(this).closest('.row').prevAll('#img_btn').find('i').attr('id');
  var cmd = this.value;
  console.log(target, cmd, id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img_btn2"><a href="#modal1" class="modal-trigger btn-flat"><i class="material-icons icone_branco">alarm</i></a></div>
<div id="img_btn"><i id="img_lamp1" class="material-icons icone_branco">lightbulb_outline</i></div>
<div id="nome_btn1" align="center">QUARTO</div>
<div id="botoes" class="row" align="center">
  <div class="switch" align="center"><label>Desligado<input id="btn_cliente_on1" class="btn_onoff" value="http://192.168.10.102" type="checkbox"><span class="lever"></span>Ligado</label></div>
</div>
```

Porem se esse `i` tem ID e as IDs só podem ser únicas podias simplesmente fazer:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_onoff', function() {
  var id = this.id;
  var target = $('#img_btn').find('i').attr('id');
  var cmd = this.value;
  console.log(target);
});
```

Comment: Perfeito!! Obrigado pela rápida resposta!

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio ótimo ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

A tag `<i>` define uma parte do texto para exibição em ***itálico***.

Não contém id, portanto não é apropriada para fazer essa lógica.

Minha sugestão é que separe com `<div>` e coloque a `class` com o mesmo nome para elementos comuns, assim terá como recuperar as informações comuns.

Elementos `<div>` tem possibilidade de utilizar `id`

A tag `<i>` fará o seguinte no seu código:

```
i {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

**Fonte:** https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp

Comment: Humm, bem lembrado, não me toquei nisso. Obrigado pelo lembrete!!